# embed video using just url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, video, youtube

given a youtube url, how can i embed the video into a page using .net c#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 you could use the [`Video.Flash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers.video.flash%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) method from the [ASP.NET Web Pages Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/11/07/using-asp-net-web-pages-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx):

```
@Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash("http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxx")
```

Here is a worthwile blog post explaining how you could implement it:

- [Video Web Helper in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC 2 - Add Videos to your Web Pages](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=622)

**Update**

If you don't want to use Microsoft's Web Pages Helpers you can of course write your own `HtmlHelper` extension method. You can find a good downloadable example for a `HtmlHelper` to display YouTube videos in ASP.NET MVC in this blog post:

- [Display youtube video in asp.net mvc using "YouTubePlayerHelper"](http://dongavipul.blogspot.com/2011/01/display-youtube-video-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

Comment: i want to avoid the ms web helper. for some reason it was messing with facebook sdk im using.

Comment: to avoid all these dependencies and keep it simple see my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

Simply add in a line like the following

```
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO_ID]?autoplay=1" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

With the autoplay= set as you like to either 0 or 1 (depending on whether you want people to actually stay on your page or not :)

Comment: Simply go to the youtube video you want, then click embed button underneath for the up to date markup you need for your page.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with HTML 5's video tag:

```
 <video id="SomeID" name="media" src="http://youtube.com/somevideo" />
```

Comment: i want to support older browsers too